# Follow-up to question: Aut(G) for G = Klein 4-group is isomorphic to $S_3$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

This is most likely a lack of understanding of wording on my part. I was considerind the Klein 4-group as the set of four permutations: the identity permutation, and three other permutations of four elements, where each of those is made up of two transposes, (i.e., 1 $\rightarrow$ 2, 2 $\rightarrow$ 1 and 3 $\rightarrow$ 4, 4 $\rightarrow$ 3) taken over the three possible such combinations of four elements.

Here, then, is my question. I am assuming (?) that Aut(G) in this case is the set of permutations of the four elements of the Klein 4-group - or the three non-identity ones for the purpose of showing isomorphic to $S_3$. If this is the case, what does it mean to have a permutation of these three permutations that I mentioned above? As always, thanks for your help.

Comment: I don't understand the question. What do you mean by "what does it mean to have a permutation of these three permutations"?

Comment: Call the three non-identity elements $x, y, z$. Then a permutation is just a permutation of the set containing $x,y,z$. Perhaps you are confused because $x,y,z$ can themselves be written as permutations, but one ignores the detailed structure of $x,y,z$ and just treats them as items that can be permuted.

Comment: @GerryMyersonThanks. That's actually my question. Using the description of {1,2,3,4} and the permutations as I mentioned, what explicitly happens to "1" for example if you call 1 $\rightarrow$ 2 etc. $x$ and call 1 $\rightarrow$ 3, etc. $y$ and you send $x$ to $y$?

Comment: @QiaochuYuanI mentioned in the comment to Gerry what I am trying to articulate. If you have these permutations representing the Klein 4-group, What happens to them as you permute the permutations amongst themselves.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Every group is a set (together with a binary operation on the set). Every automorphism of a group $G$ is a bijective function from the underlying set of $G$ to itself (which in addition respects the operation of $G$). So every automorphism of a group $G$ can be viewed as a subgroup of the group of all permutations on the underlying set of $G$; in fact, since an automorphism must send the identity of $G$ to itself, you can even view every automorphism of $G$ as a permutation of the set $G-\{e\}$.

Here you are getting a bit confused because you are viewing your group $G$ as a subgroup of $S_4$ (nothing wrong with that), and then you are trying to understand $\mathrm{Aut}(G)$ (which can be viewed as a subgroup of $S_{G-{e}} \cong S_3$) as acting on the set $\{1,2,3,4\}$ *as well*. While *some* automorphisms can be defined in terms of an action on $\{1,2,3,4\}$, not every automorphism can.

If you view $G$ as the set $\{\mathrm{id}, (1\;2), (3\;4), (1\;2)(3\;4)\}$, then letting
$$\begin{align*}
x &= (1\;2),\\
y &= (3\;4),\\
z &= (1\;2)(3\;4)\\
e &= \mathrm{id}
\end{align*}$$
then the automorphisms of $G$ will always map $e$ to itself, and so you can view the automorphisms as being elements of $S_{\{x,y,z\}}$, the permutation group of $\{x,y,z\}$. The elements of the automorphism group are then (written in 2-line format):
$$\begin{align*}
\mathrm{id}_{\{x,y,z\}} &= \left(\begin{array}{ccc}
x & y & z\\
x & y & z
\end{array}\right)\\
f_1 &= \left(\begin{array}{ccc}
x & y & z\\
y & z & x
\end{array}\right)\\
f_2 &=\left(\begin{array}{ccc}
x & y & z\\
z & x & y
\end{array}\right)\\
f_3 &= \left(\begin{array}{ccc}
x & y & z\\
y & x & z
\end{array}\right)\\
f_4 &= \left(\begin{array}{ccc}
x & y & z\\
z & y & x
\end{array}\right)\\
f_5 &= \left(\begin{array}{ccc}
x & y & z\\
x & z & y
\end{array}\right)
\end{align*}$$
and you can verify that each of them is an automorphism; since every automorphism corresponds to a unique element of $S_{\{x,y,z\}}$, and every element of this group is an automorphism, then this *is* the automorphism group.

However, you are trying to view your group $G$ as a subgroup of $S_4$. Can the automorphisms of $S_4$ be "induced" by some permutation of $\{1,2,3,4\}$? Equivalently:

> If we view the Klein $4$-group $G$ as the subgroup of $S_4$ generated by $(1\;2)$ and $(3\;4)$, is every automorphism of $G$ induced by conjugation by an element of $S_4$?

Well, it doesn't. The reason it doesn't is that $x$, $y$, and $z$ don't all have the same cycle structure: conjugation by elements of $S_4$ (or more precisely, by elements of the normalizer of $G$ in $S_4$) will necessarily  map $z$ to itself, because $z$ is the only element with its cycle structure (product of two disjoint transpositions) in $G$. So the only automorphisms that can be viewed as coming from "acting on ${1,2,3,4}$" are the identity and $f_3$

**Added:** *However:* it is possible to view the Klein $4$-group as a *different* subgroup of $S_4$: identify $x\mapsto (1\;2)(3\;4)$; $y\mapsto (1\;3)(2\;4)$, $z\mapsto (1\;4)(2\;3)$. It is not hard to verify that this is a subgroup of order $4$, and since it has three elements of order $2$, it is isomorphic to the Klein $4$-group. **Now** you can indeed realize every automorphism of $G$ via conjugation by an element of $S_4$ (in several different ways). Here's one way: the automorphism $\mathrm{id}$ can be realized as conjugation by the identity. The automorphism $f_1$ is given by conjugation by $(2\;3\;4)$; $f_2$ is given by conjugation by $(2\;4\;3)$; the automorphism $f_3$ is given by conjugation by $(2\;3)$; $f_4$ is given by conjugation by $(2\;4)$; and $f_5$ is given by conjugation by $(3\;4)$. You can now easily see that the automorphism group is indeed isomorphic to $S_3$, since it corresponds precisely to the subgroup of $S_4$ that fixes $1$ (you can take any of the other four one-point stabilizers as well).

Comment: @ArturoMagidinThanks. And congratulations for passing the 100k milestone. In addition to giving great answers, you always seem to have the insight/patience to write at the level of the questioner.

Comment: @Andrew: I just added something you might find closer to what you were thinking about. And thanks.

Comment: @ArturoMagidinThanks again. That was what I had a problem with - as I was starting with the x,y,z you just added but then couldn't see what to do with them to get the automorphisms.

Comment: We are talking about outer automorphism, not inner automorphism of Klein group, correct? (there is no inner one here, yes?)

Comment: @wonderich: Abelian groups have no (nontrivial) inner automorphisms. Generally, we don't talk about outer automorphisms of abelian groups, just automorphisms.

Comment: This Amazing @ArturoMagidin, this Is exactly the answer I was lookiing for. So basically, the automorphism group of $K_4$ Is isomorphic to any of the 4 stabilizer of each $S_4$ points, right? I was also wondering about whether the stabilizer ican bè seen as a subgroup of the normalizer, since the former solved the problem, while the latter did not, as you explained above.

Answer (score 6):

Let $G=\{1,a_1(=a_2a_3),a_2(=a_1a_3),a_3(=a_1a_2)\}$ be Klein's $4$-group. Consider the map:

\begin{alignat}{2}
  \varphi: S_3&\longrightarrow& \operatorname{Aut}(G) \\
  \sigma&\longmapsto& \varphi_\sigma:G &\longrightarrow G \\
  &&1&\longmapsto 1 \\
  &&a_i&\longmapsto a_{\sigma(i)} \\
\end{alignat}

- **Good definition of $\varphi$** (codomain). Firstly, for every $\sigma\in S_3$, $\varphi_\sigma\in \operatorname{Sym}(G)$; moreover, $\forall\sigma\in S_3$:

$$\varphi_\sigma(1a_i)=\varphi_\sigma(a_i)=1\varphi_\sigma(a_i)=\varphi_\sigma(1)\varphi_\sigma(a_i)$$

and ($i=1,2,3$; $\{i,j,k\}=\{1,2,3\}$):

\begin{alignat}{1}
&\varphi_\sigma(a_i^2)=(\varphi_\sigma(a_i))^2&&\iff 1=a_{\sigma(i)}^2 &&&:\text{true}\space\forall\sigma\in S_3 \\
&\varphi_\sigma(a_ia_j)=\varphi_\sigma(a_i)\varphi_\sigma(a_j)&&\iff a_{\sigma(k)}=a_{\sigma(i)}a_{\sigma(j)} &&&:\text{true}\space\forall\sigma\in S_3 \\
\end{alignat}

Therefore, $\varphi_\sigma\in\operatorname{Aut}(G)$ for every $\sigma\in S_3$.

- **Injectivity of $\varphi$**.

\begin{alignat}{1}
\varphi_\sigma=\varphi_\tau &\Longrightarrow a_{\sigma(i)}=a_{\tau(i)}, \forall i \\
&\Longrightarrow \sigma(i)=\tau(i), \forall i \\
&\Longrightarrow \sigma=\tau \\
\end{alignat}

- **Surjectivity of $\varphi$**. Every automorphism of $G$, say $\lambda$, must send $1$ to $1$, $a_1$ to some element of $\{a_1,a_2,a_3\}$ (say $a_{\bar i}$), $a_2$ to some element of $\{a_1,a_2,a_3\}\setminus\{a_{\bar i}\}$ (say $a_{\bar j})$, and $a_3$ to the lonely element of $\{a_1,a_2,a_3\}\setminus\{a_{\bar i},a_{\bar j}\}$ (say $a_{\bar k}$). Thus, $\lambda=\varphi_\sigma$, where $\sigma$ is the permutation defined by $\sigma(1)=\bar i$, $\sigma(2)=\bar j$, $\sigma(3)=\bar k$.
- **$\varphi$ is a group homomorphism**. In fact:

\begin{alignat}{1}
\varphi_{\sigma\tau}(1) = 1 =\varphi_\sigma(1)=\varphi_\sigma(\varphi_\tau(1))=(\varphi_\sigma\varphi_\tau)(1)
\end{alignat}

and

\begin{alignat}{1}
\varphi_{\sigma\tau}(a_i) &= a_{(\sigma\tau)(i)} \\
&= a_{\sigma(\tau(i))} \\
&= \varphi_\sigma(a_{\tau(i)}) \\
&= \varphi_\sigma(\varphi_\tau(a_i)) \\
&= (\varphi_\sigma\varphi_\tau)(a_i) \\
\end{alignat}

whence $\varphi_{\sigma\tau}=\varphi_\sigma\varphi_\tau$.

By this all:

$$\operatorname{Aut}(G)\stackrel{\varphi}{\cong}S_3$$

Answer (score 2):

It is also interesting to note that $Aut(V_4)$ is isomorphic to $GL_2(F_2)$, i.e. the general linear group of dimension $2$ over $\Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z$. The one-to-one correspondence between them is fairly straight forward.

Comment: The observation is correct, but offered without any details (as offered by previous posts) and without squarely answering the Question about $S_3$, thus would have been more suitable as a Comment.

Comment: @hardmath I think the missing details are $|GL_2(\mathbb Z_2)|=(2^2-1)(2^2-2)=6$ and there's only one non-abelian group of order $6$ upto isomorphism i.e., $S_3$.